Gratis Windows app to burn an MKV to normal DVD video format for an old DVD player?
Any ideas? I use Windows 11 and want to burn an MKV for a friend who has a very old DVD player and no PC.

consider to close/delete one of the two questions you've posted as they are identical. This practice is frowned upon in SE and may result in both of them being closed by moderators. Get ahead of the game and delete one of them yourself.

T'other has been burninated. I figured there might be a way to do it using only Windows, hence SuperUser. Or, it might require an app, hence here
